# %in% suddenly stopped logically responding

Tags: r, list, match, any

I have a list full of generic drugs, and a user makes an input to check if this drug exists in my list (scraped from Medline). The program checks if this drug exists in my list . The thing is that i checked the drug existence with:

`vast<-user_comp %in% medline_comps[1]`

user_comp being the user drug input and medline_comps the list of drug names
which was always true.

And the variable "vast" was always true because for example "Phenylephrine" exists in medline_comps. The thing is i haven's changed anything in the code and suddenly vast started returning FALSE, i have tried rebooting R, clearing every object from the workspace and without any change `%in%` started returning FALSE instead of TRUE. I double checked the existense of the drug in the list, i even copy pasted the drug in the list and put it in the user input and is still returning FALSE when in the past was returning TRUE.

Is there a special reason why R could give you different results when you havent changed anything in the code?

An example of my list is:

```
medline_comps[1]

[[1]]
[1] "Phenylephrine"               "Pyrethrin and Piperonyl Butoxide Topical"              
[3] "Antipyrine-Benzocaine Otic"  "Hydrocortisone
```

So if i input Phenylephrine, vast should definetly be TRUE as it was before but now is returning only FALSE, is there any logical explanation to this?

Comment: Try `user_comp %in% medline_comps[[1]]` (note the double brackets).

Comment: It returns TRUE, so i did change the code somehow. It was the way i was accesing the list, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `user_comp %in% medline_comps[[1]]` (note the double brackets).

Your output indicates what's going on here:

```
medline_comps[1]
# [[1]] 
# [1] "Phenylephrine" "Pyrethrin and Piperonyl Butoxide Topical" 
# [3] "Antipyrine-Benzocaine Otic" "Hydrocortisone
```

The single bracket returns a list, whereas you wanted to test for the presence of an item in the vector contained in the list, in which case you would use the double brackets. See e.g. [The difference between [] and [[]] notations for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis).